# An App disappeared after downloading, Where is it?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

When I download an app from play store, The download process is completed (100%) but the app disappeared and silently failed to install on my phone.

**I would like to know where the source file of the app is downloaded so that I can reach it and install it manually.**

Phone Type: Techno P5

Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean

Phone storage: 2GB ( 1GB free )

SD Card: 8GB (3.6GB free)

512 MB of RAM

1.2 GHz dual core processor

App size: 100 MB

Comment: Can you link the app what you are trying to install on your device?

Comment: @BálintBabics - This question is well-formed, and almost all other information is freely provided. My guess is that the app we are being covert about is probably cracked, or something else.

Comment: Is the app in question a theme?

Comment: @wbogacz well, without knowing the exact app (e.g. theme, icon packs, game), we can't give the exact answer though....

Comment: Can you find the app on the Android's app managers (from Settings)? If not, then it's not installed, and the source file (e.g. APK) is not stored on the device.

Comment: @BálintBabics 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pikpok.turbo&hl=en
Here is the link of the app. I also need a general answer so that I can fix this issue for any other apps.

Comment: @AndrewT. Well, I can't. It is OK if I downloaded the app again. But How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Not its a game. I provided the link in a previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is an issue with your phone with Google Play not installing correctly.

- If the app is in Google Play you can't install it manually
- When you go back into Google Play and search for the app you have installed, do you see the button *Install* or *Open*?

  - If the buttons *Uninstall* & *Open* show the app is installed
  - if the button *Install* shows you will have to reinstall